# WordPress > Activating plugin makes site go blank in one theme, not in another. Generated source identical

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Strangest thing. When I activate this specific plugin, the public side of the site goes blank (nothing but a white screen with blank view source). However, when I test the site with the wordpress default theme, the plugin does not conflict and the site works fine.

The interesting thing is that I've compared the generated source (using FF's webmaster tools) with and without plugin activated and in each case they are identical. This led me to believe that perhaps the plugin was altering htaccess, however, that file is the same whether or not the plugin is active or not.

How can I find out what is causing the problem with this plugin?

The plugin is called "Crawl Rate Tracker".

Answer (score 0):

sometimes i got this problem when a theme and a plugin use the same function name. the page just white and blank. but after i change it name, the plugin show perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but possibly a conflict in CSS style names? If the HTML is there, it's probably the CSS doing it.